# Arduino changes COM port when uploading code (Windows)

Tags: windows, arduino, arduino-mkr1000

I'm testing the new **MKR1000** in Windows. I'm having an annoying issue that causes Windows to re-install the Arduino drivers in another port every time I upload new code into the board. E.g.:

If the Arduino is installed on *COM4*, when I upload code into the board Windows decides to install Arduino on *COM5*. This causes the IDE to tell me that the upload procedure failed (as there is no Arduino connected on COM5), but strangely enough, the code actually uploads correctly.

If I want to open the Serial monitor I need to go in the IDE and change the Arduino port back to COM4. It's super annoying to have Windows go through the driver installation procedure every time I upload new code into Arduino.

Some generic information:

- This happens in both Windows 7 & 8
- I'm troubleshooting with the Blink example (pin 6)
- The problems happens with both the Arduino IDE (1.6.11) & Arduino Create (1.0.38)
- The MKR1000 is correctly installed in Windows, showing up in the Device Manager as 'Arduino MKR1000 (COM4)'
- SAMD Board 1.6.6 is installed
- Tried multiple USB cables

The error in the Arduino IDE is:

```
Arduino: 1.6.11 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino MKR1000"
Sketch uses 7,972 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262,144 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM4
PORTS {COM3, COM4, } / {COM3, } => {}
PORTS {COM3, } / {COM3, } => {}
PORTS {COM3, } / {COM3, } => {}
PORTS {COM3, } / {COM3, COM5, } => {COM5, }
Found upload port: COM5
C:\Users\40009929\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\bossac\1.6.1-arduino/bossac.exe -i -d --port=COM5 -U true -i -e -w -v C:\Users\40009929\AppData\Local\Temp\build9c9ef3bdfe2fccb480bc6e4bac749e41.tmp/Blink.ino.bin -R 
Set binary mode
readWord(addr=0)=0x20007ffc
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x410cc601
readWord(addr=0x41002018)=0x10010305
version()=v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ] Nov 24 2015 11:35:16
chipId=0x10010005
Connected at 921600 baud
readWord(addr=0)=0x20007ffc
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x410cc601
readWord(addr=0x41002018)=0x10010305
Atmel SMART device 0x10010005 found
write(addr=0x20004000,size=0x34)
writeWord(addr=0x20004030,value=0x10)
writeWord(addr=0x20004020,value=0x20008000)
Device       : ATSAMD21G18A
readWord(addr=0)=0x20007ffc
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x410cc601
readWord(addr=0x41002018)=0x10010305
Chip ID      : 10010005
version()=v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ] Nov 24 2015 11:35:16
Version      : v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ] Nov 24 2015 11:35:16
Address      : 8192
Pages        : 3968
Page Size    : 64 bytes
Total Size   : 248KB
Planes       : 1
Lock Regions : 16
Locked       : readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
readWord(addr=0x41004020)=0xffff
none
readWord(addr=0x41004018)=0
Security     : false
Boot Flash   : true
readWord(addr=0x40000834)=0x7000a
BOD          : true
readWord(addr=0x40000834)=0x7000a
BOR          : true
Arduino      : FAST_CHIP_ERASE
Arduino      : FAST_MULTI_PAGE_WRITE
Arduino      : CAN_CHECKSUM_MEMORY_BUFFER
Erase flash
chipErase(addr=0x2000)
done in 0.823 seconds

Write 8124 bytes to flash (127 pages)
write(addr=0x20005000,size=0x1000)
writeBuffer(scr_addr=0x20005000, dst_addr=0x2000, size=0x1000)

SAM-BA operation failed
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

[===============               ] 50% (64/127 pages)write(addr=0x20005000,size=0xfc0)
writeBuffer(scr_addr=0x20005000, dst_addr=0x3000, size=0xfc0)

[==============================] 100% (127/127 pages)
done in 0.051 seconds

Verify 8124 bytes of flash with checksum.
checksumBuffer(start_addr=0x2000, size=0x1000) = 7923
checksumBuffer(start_addr=0x3000, size=0xfbc) = b6c0
Verify successful
done in 0.010 seconds
CPU reset.
readWord(addr=0)=0x20007ffc
readWord(addr=0xe000ed00)=0x410cc601
readWord(addr=0x41002018)=0x10010305
writeWord(addr=0xe000ed0c,value=0x5fa0004)
```

In Arduino Create the problem is the same:

```
Atmel SMART device 0x10010005 found

Device : ATSAMD21G18A

Chip ID : 10010005

Version : v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ] Nov 24 2015 11:35:16

Address : 8192

Pages : 3968

Page Size : 64 bytes

Total Size : 248KB

Planes : 1

Lock Regions : 16

Locked : none

Security : false

Boot Flash : true

BOD : true

BOR : true

Arduino : FAST_CHIP_ERASE

Arduino : FAST_MULTI_PAGE_WRITE

Arduino : CAN_CHECKSUM_MEMORY_BUFFER

Erase flash

done in 0.822 seconds

Write 8116 bytes to flash (127 pages)


[=============== ] 50% (64/127 pages)
[==============================] 100% (127/127 pages)

done in 0.052 seconds

Verify 8116 bytes of flash with checksum.

Verify successful

done in 0.010 seconds

CPU reset.

SAM-BA operation failed

Could not program the board
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi based on your output there might be a reason why its doing that. 
Other developers can correct me if I am wrong.

When you upload a code to the ATSAMD21,

-->The IDE/development environment used will put the board into bootloader mode for 5seconds. (At 1200bps)  //STEP 1

-->But when it uploads the program to the board the bootloader locks after successful upload and changes its port //STEP 2

-->At STEP 1, the micro works as NATIVE USB Port and calls PROGRAMMING USB Port

-->At STEP 2, the micro finishes programming and after reset it goes back to its default state - NATIVE USB Port (this is where your COM port changes to the next port).

-->If you observe carefully when you open hyperterm  and open the connected Arduino port (say COM4 for example) at 1200bps in 5sec, in your device manager you will notice a USB Serial Device in place of your Arduino MKR board.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same problem too. Try to download arduino advance ide (enhanced release).

[Here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=118440.0)

This should help because when it does changes port it will tell you and ask you if you do want to.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I'm hoping to use the MKR1000 with Arduino Create (browser IDE).

Comment: There is already one:

[link](https://circuits.io/)

you can upload your code to arduino directly from here

Please consider vote in case you liked

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix for SAM-BA operation failed.
Situation
Windows 7 with USB3 port  (previously worked on Windows 7 machine with only USB2 ports)
Uploading to Sparkfun Redboard Turbo

Put a USB 2 hub between the PC and the board.

SAM-BA error no longer occurres